# Написать функцию подсчёта гласных Pascal

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте!

Нужно написать функцию на паскале, которая считает количество гласных в тексте. Функция получает `var t:text;`.

С алгоритмом проблем нет. Какой синтаксис считывания символов (не строк) в паскале?

Использовать можно только packed array, это стандартный паскаль, не турбо и прочие.

Спасибо.

Вариант считывание в цикле вначале строку, а потом символов не работает для типа text.

Answer (score 1):

```
vat t:text;c:char;cnt:integer;
.....
cnt:=0;
assign(t,FileName);
reset(t);
while not eof(t) do
begin
 read(t,c);
 if pos(c,'уеыаоэяиюё')<>0 then cnt := cnt+1;
end;
close(t);
```

Могу ошибаться с функциями, которые поддерживает стандартный паскаль

Comment: @Magos, точно не верно. Нужно делать проверку eoln(t) и функция pos() не по стандарту.